# Python regular expression re.match, why this code does not work?

Tags: python, regex

This is written in Python,

```
import re
s='1 89059809102/30589533 IronMan 30 Santa Ana Massage table / IronMan 30 Santa Ana Massage table'
pattern='\s(\d{11})/(\d{8})'
re.match(pattern,s)
```

it returns none.

I tried taking the brackets off,

```
pattern='\s\d{11}/\d{8}'
```

It still returns `none`.

My questions are:

1. Why the re.match does not find anything?
2. What is the difference with or without bracket in pattern?

Comment: @nhahtdh: `\s` and `\d` have no meaning in normal python strings, so in this specific case there is no difference and the backslashes do not require escaping.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right, but raw string is still quite useful to clear the confusion. Different language has different treatment for ``\`` followed by a character that does not form an escape sequence.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I quite agree; using `r''` raw strings for regular expressions is certainly a great idea and is the best practice. Just in this case the OP is lucky and there is no difference. :-)

Comment: @nhahtdh: Almost all languages that use ``\`` one-character escape sequences follow the ISO C standard though (see the [third column on the control codes table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters)), so *generally* speaking you can assume there are at most 9 such escape codes in any language that supports these. In fact, I know of no programming language that supports such escape codes and support more than those 9 (python itself supports 8 of them, `\e` not seen as often).

Comment: @nhahtdh: LBNL: Of all the regular expression anchors and character classes that could be confused, *only* `\b` has a meaning as both a character escape (backspace) and as a regular expression anchor (beginning of a word boundary). :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No, I am referring to how the ``\`` followed by a non-escape sequence is treated **in a string literal**. In JS (and C, IIRC), the ``\`` evaporates. Java gives compile error. Python is one that preserves the ``\`` if an escape sequence is not formed.

Comment: @nhahtdh: ah, yes, I see what you mean there. Sorry for having misread that.

Comment: Thank you guys for giving me recommendations!

Answer (score 43):

`re.match` "matches" since the beginning of the string, but there is an extra `1`.

Use `re.search` instead, which will "search" anywhere within the string. And, in your case, also find something:

```
>>> re.search(pattern,s).groups()
('89059809102', '30589533')
```

If you remove the brackets in pattern, it will still return a valid `_sre.SRE_Match`, object, but with empty `groups`:

```
>>> re.search('\s\d{11}/\d{8}',s).groups()
()
```