# Why isn't this regex matching a string with percentage symbol?

Tags: python, regex, string, match, word-boundary

I have a file which has the following input :

```
xa%1bc
ba%1bc
.
.
```

and so on. I want to use `match` and `regex` to identify the lines which have `a%1b`in them. 
I am using

```
 import re
 p1 = re.compile(r'\ba%1b\b', flags=re.I)
 if re.match(p1,linefromfile):
    continue
```

It doesnt seem to detect the line with %1. What is the issue? Thanks

Comment: The issue is `\b` around your pattern. It stands for "word boundary", so it wouldn't match any of your examples. Also, you don't need regex to simply check for a substring.

Comment: There are several problems. First you should just [be using `in`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319922/python-check-if-word-is-in-a-string). Second, you are checking for word boundaries where none exist. Third, you are only looking at the beginning of the string with `match` when [you need `search` to look in the whole string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933771/python-regular-expression-re-match-why-this-code-does-not-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` only search the pattern at the beginning of the string, if you want to find out if a string contains a pattern, use `search` instead. Besides you don't need the word boundary, `\b`:

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Scan through string looking for
>   the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a
>   match, and return a corresponding match object. Return None if no
>   position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is
>   different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the
>   string.
>
> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the
>   beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a
>   corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match
>   the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

```
import re
if re.search(r"a%1b", "xa%1bc"):
    print("hello")
# hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if 'a%1b' in linefromfile:
```

**OR**

if you need regex

```
if re.match('a%1b', linefromfile):
```