# Python re.match not matching string ending with ".number"

Tags: regex, python-2.7

As part of a bigger code I am trying to check if a **string(filename)** ends with **".number"**
However, re.match (re.compile and match) just wont match the pattern at end of the string.

Code:

```
import re
f = ".1.txt.2"
print re.match('\.\d$',f)
```

Output:

```
>>> print re.match('\.\d$',f)
None
```

Any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expression re.match, why this code does not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933771/python-regular-expression-re-match-why-this-code-does-not-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `search` instead of `match`

---

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

> re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string,
>   while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string.

Comment: Wow - yep.  Surprising. I think `re.match('^.*(\.\d)$',f).group(1)` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import re
word_list = ["c1234", "c12" ,"c"]
for word in word_list:
    m = re.search(r'.*\d+',word)
    if m is not None:
        print(m.group(),"-match")
    else:
        print(word[-1], "- nomatch")
```