# How can I get Python to match 'x264' using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to find all files that contain certain variations of a codec in their name, but when I try to execute the following code, I get nothing but '*** Exited normally ***'

- x264, X264, h264, H264
- as above, but with a period between the X/H and 264

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import re

rootdir = "/mnt/local/int002/Downloads/Complete"
regex = re.compile('x264')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
    if regex.match(file):
       print(file)
```

Comment: Try `re.seach`?

Comment: Not every string problem is a regex problem. What's wrong with [`"x264" in filename`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)?

Comment: Because I need it more complex than that, I'm just starting with the basics.

Comment: `re.match` only matches at the beginning of the string - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expression re.match, why this code does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933771/python-regular-expression-re-match-why-this-code-does-not-work) ..Or.. [What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)

Comment: I was so focused on the regex itself, I didn't even look at whether .match was correct or not.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use a regex, try `re.search`. `re.match` only matches the beginning of the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import re

rootdir = "/mnt/local/int002/Downloads/Complete"
regex = re.compile('x264')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
    if regex.search(file):
       print(file)
```