# python re match ip address

Tags: python, python-re

I have simple script for combining through ip addresses. I'd like to regex the ip from the following output

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-11 15:04 EST
Nmap scan report for host.com (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.14s latency).
```

I tried using this tool: https://pythex.org/. I was able to get a match with the following pattern

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

however this code returns 0 matches

```
regex = re.match("(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})",output)
print(regex)
```

the expected output should be `127.0.0.1`. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try like this  r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"  Replace regular expression with this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expression re.match, why this code does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933771/python-regular-expression-re-match-why-this-code-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) matches a pattern at the beginning of the given string. It looks like what you want is [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) or [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
output = '''
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-11 15:04 EST
Nmap scan report for host.com (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.14s latency).'''

regex = re.findall("(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", output)

print(regex) # ['127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `re.search`

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Nmap scan report for host.com (127.0.0.1)'
>>> re.search(r"(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}", text).group()
'127.0.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

with re.match you can use it as follows:

```
output = 'Your output'
ip = re.match(r'\(([\d\.]*)\)').groups()[0]
```

Explaination : re.match will return a class which is surrounded by brackets and have "." and digits only. The groups() will then return all matching groups. the string at index[0] will be the match for it.