# Python: re.match (r"1", "[1]") returns empty

Tags: python, python-re

Why does Python's regex module not recognize "[1]" in this following code?

```
In [43]: re.match (r"1",  "[1]")

In [44]:
```

whereas this works:

```
In [46]: re.match (r"1",  "123")
Out[46]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
```

Comment: From python.org: `match() Determine if the RE matches at the beginning of the string.` https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#performing-matches

Comment: This is expected behavior, `re.match` does only look for pattern at beginning, if you wish to match anywhere in string use `re.search`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python regular expression re.match, why this code does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933771/python-regular-expression-re-match-why-this-code-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

From [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/):

> [`re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)
>
> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string match** the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.
>
> ...
>
> If you want to locate a **match anywhere in string**, use `search()` instead (see also [`search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)).

Since your 'string' starts with an `[`, it's not captured.

As suggested by the docs, using `re.search(r"1",  "[1]")` does match it since it will match anywhere in the string

---

> whereas this works:
>
> ```
> In [46]: re.match (r"1",  "123")`
> Out[46]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
> ```

Here the 'string' **starts with** the pattern and is being matched as expected